# Contact Form 7 pre email processing

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I want to save the form to a custom table in my WP database. The email should still be sent.

I have [read this post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-contact-form-7-insert-contact-name-and-email-in-database-after-successful-submission) and came up with the below code which is currently in my theme's `function.php` file:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'process_form' );

function process_form( $cf7 )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if($cf7->posted_data['_wpcf7'] == 20) {
        $wpdb->insert('newsletter_signups',
            array(
                'name'=>$cf7->posted_data['name'],
                'email'=>$cf7->posted_data['email']
            )
        );
    }
}
```

If I take the `insert` out of the `if`-statement, and give it fixed values, it saves to the database. However it does not save to the table if I do as above. Now I'm assuming that it's because it's not receiving any data. I don't know how to debug the variable that it receives, as it's an ajax request. If I `print_r($cf7)` it doesn't show anything in my element inspector or on the network tab (in Chrome). So, I have 2 questions regarding this:

1. How can I debug the variables passed here?
2. How can I change this function so that it does my processing?

Comment: How is this not specific to wordpress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contact form 7 changed classes in 3.9 version. Now this is how it goes.

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'process_form' );

function process_form( $cf7 ) {

    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

    if ( $submission ) {
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
    }

    if( $cf7->id() == 20 ) {
        $wpdb->insert('newsletter_signups',
            array(
                'name' => $posted_data['name'],
                'email' => $posted_data['email']
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Read more about [change here](http://contactform7.com/2014/07/02/contact-form-7-39-beta/).